# android Material Edittext error appears on left if RTL is implemented

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, material-design

I'm working on application which support multi-language (English and Arabic).

EditText error appears on left side if app language in Arabic. I have tried all the tricks like

```
gravity=start 
textAlignment=viewStart
layoutDirection=anyRtl
```

etc but not working. Please help me :(

Here is the screen shot of issue am facing.

[image]

Here is the code

```
<appname.util.customview.MaterialEditText
        android:id="@+id/met_email_phone"
        style="@style/material_edit_text"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_large_30"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_large_30"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_xlarge"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:hint="@string/email_phone"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        app:met_primaryColor="@color/met_underline" />
```

And style of edittext is

```
<style name="material_edit_text">
    <item name="android:gravity">start</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    <item name="android:maxLength">30</item>
    <item name="android:textDirection">anyRtl</item>
    <item name="android:textAlignment">viewStart</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginStart">@dimen/margin_large</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginEnd">@dimen/margin_large</item>
    <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@color/tc_header</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">@dimen/margin_small</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Show its `XML` code.

Comment: @HassanUsman please check the updated question

Comment: is that some custom library for edittext? Does the same happen with android native one?

Comment: @poss yes its a library here is the link 
 https://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText

Comment: Try without using the library. To make sure it's not just the lib issue. if it is, raise it on github as issue.

Comment: @Rahul You are using gravity start that mean left+start , try with gravity set to end or right

Answer (score 1):

Set these two properties to locale

```
 android:layoutDirection="locale"
 android:textDirection="locale"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below properties in MaterialEditText and remove gravity if any and textAlignment also

```
 android:layoutDirection="rtl"
 android:textDirection="rtl"
```

This will be helpful if you are using specific Layout(for eg. layout-ar). Better avoid custom library and Simply use

```
 android:layoutDirection="locale"
 android:textDirection="locale"
```

as suggested by Nermeen Saleh